# Finding percentage land cover classes in a shapefile in R

Tags: r, raster, tiff

I have shapefile in R and a tiff file of land cover classes. How can I find the percentage of land cover classes in the shapefile? For instance how much land is present in the study area in that shapefile?

```
#example data for cover
rat <- levels(raster2 )[[1]]
rat[["landcover"]] <- c("land","ocean/lake", "rivers")
levels(raster2 ) <- rat

#and a raster
raster1 <-  raster(matrix(c(1,1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7),ncol =3))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a *minimal, self-contained, reproducible example*:

Raster data

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(ncol=36, nrow=18)
set.seed(111)
values(r) <- sample(3, 18*36, replace=TRUE)
```

Polygon

```
cds1 <- rbind(c(-180,-20), c(-160,5), c(-60, 0), c(-160,-60), c(-180,-20))
polys <- spPolygons(cds1)
```

Solution

```
x <- extract(r, polys)
table(x)
#x
# 1  2  3 
#16  9 13
```

Comment: My values are coming like these  124886  443141    2570   46059  395207 etc, are they form of area? As I would like to know the percentages of each land cover class.

Answer (score 1):

I have written an R package to do this.

Package name is SpatialCover and can be found on Github. It requires packages raster and sp.

The Percent.cov function will do what you need. You'll need to ensure that your polygon/shapefile has an ID field. If there are multiple polygons in the shapefile, Percent.cov will calculate the frequency of each cover type within each polygon individually.

```
  library(SpatialCover)
  library(raster)
  library(sp)
  library(rgdal)

  shapefile<- readOGR(dsn=wd, layer="filename.shp")
  lcraster<- raster("filepathname/rasterfilename.tif")

  FreqTable<- Percent.cov(vectorlayer=shapefile, rasterlayer=lcraster, zoneID=ID)
```

You should then get a table that looks something like this

| zoneID | CoverType | PercentCover |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Land | 20 |
| 1 | Ocean/Lake | 70 |
| 1 | Rivers | 10 |

Hopefully this helps. There is also an example with the package.